# Difficulty using collection_check_boxes with has_many :through join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue when trying to save attributes to a join model. I get an error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

I have implemented this before without problem in other apps so it is extra confusing where I am going wrong.

I have the following models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :product_image, :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :product_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  has_many :package_items
  has_many :packages, through: :package_items
end
```

--

```
class PackageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :package 
    belongs_to :product
end
```

--

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :package_image, :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :package_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  has_many :package_items
  has_many :products, through: :package_items
end
```

When I save a package it should save all the products that the package contains in the package_items table. I am using the `collection_check_boxes` helper in my form and this is working fine.

```
 <%= form_for @package,  :url => packages_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @package.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="center">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@package.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this package from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @package.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 field">
    <%= f.label :name, 'Package Name', :class => "text-center form-header" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text-center form-text"  %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12 field">
    <%= f.label :package_image, 'Package Image', :class => "text-center form-header" %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :package_image %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12 field">
    <%= f.label :price, 'Price Per Day', :class => "text-center form-header" %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price, :class => "text-center form-text"  %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12 field">
  <%= f.label :products %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12 actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However when I submit the form I get the `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)` error with it highlighting my strong params method in the packages controller:

```
def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:name, :price, :package_image, :product_ids [])
    end
```

I cannot see anything obvious in the logs. Any pointers would be much appreciated. It feels like I have gone through all of the web and SO at this stage and I can't get past this. Essentially what I am trying to achieve is the same as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658759/difficulty-using-collection-check-boxes).

Comment: is the error coming from the `collection_check_boxes`?

Comment: Yes. If I remove that it saves the package fine. It was only since adding the collection_check_boxes field to the form and the `:product_ids []` to strong params that the issue started.

Comment: Maybe the syntax of your collection box is wrong, did you take a look at the [helpers](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is something simple. A missing hash rocket

```
:product_ids => []
```

in strong params.